# Laravel Mix import CSS to JS file causes endless loop on npm watch

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I got CSS file that I want to import into JS file.
Both files are run through Laravel Mix.

When I run command "npm run watch" it causes endless loop. If I dont cancel the npm watch, it just keeps building and building all over again.

[image]

If I import static CSS file, it works fine. But I keep updating CSS file from time to time, so I don't want to always copy that compiled CSS file just so JS file can import it without "crashing".

Here is how mix looks like:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/test.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/test.js', 'public/js');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

And how I import CSS from public folder in test.js:

```
import style from '../../../public/css/test.css';
```

What should I do to get this work?

Comment: What if you pull the CSS in at runtime instead of compile time?

Comment: Thats an option, but not sure how thats gonna affect performance on a larger scale project with that extra request. But that is a simple solution indeed.

Comment: If it's cached properly, there shouldn't be much of a performance hit if you defer it until it's needed.